# Topeak rack - rear light bracket is annoying

Tags: rack

My wife has a Topeak Explorer rack.It has an bracket on the rear for a light or reflector. It is useless to mount any of the rear lights we own and is ugly. Anyone find any use for it or cut it off? I really like the rack and bag mounting system but loathe that weird metal bracket. Topeak appears to sell a light for it, but not a very good one IMHO. Thanks for any answers.

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles!  Just a suggestion, but you'll probably get a better response (more interest) if you include a photo of your rack showing the bracket you're talking about.  Most people won't be motivated enough to go searching for an image of the rack and then figure out what you're talking about, so the more help you give them the better.  Bonus points for drawing a freehand circle to clearly indicate it. :)

Comment: Yes, a photo indicating what you want to cut off would help. On Tubus racks I think the plate for rear lights also acts as a cross brace which I wouldn’t cut off.

Comment: Unclear what your problem is with the bracket.

Comment: Are you sure that the bracket does not stabilize the rack?

Comment: The metal bracket comes with a plastic adapter, which also didn't fit my light, but was easy to drill.  So I have a hardwired red strobe and white frontlight  that are powered off an 18V drill battery that lives in the rack bag.  Works for me.

Comment: If its steel you might choose to fold it up underneath.  Aluminium will crack, but steel could be bent back down in the future, certainly enough to hold a light/reflector.

Answer (score 3):

Sure you can cut it off after all you bought it.

Personally, I would keep it as you never know down the road if you want to mount something on there and it is not all that ugly.

For example what if you want to buy a rear facing bike rader (e.g. Garmin Varia) that has really poor factory mounting hardware. For me it took almost a week of periodically thinking how can I mount this thing to my road bike without risking it falling off and keeping my underseat bag where I have my flat kit. Finally I came up with a solution that involved a 3rd party bracket and the light strap on my underseat bag. I certainly would not have expected to use that strap on my bag in that manner when I bought it almost 2 years ago. So if I was just to say well let me cut it off, I would probably be buying a new bag in order to run my current setup.

Until you find a better use for the area, you could always try to use the area to add more visibility with things like a reflective sticker or even reflective circles that screw into the holes already cut in it.

Hope that helps.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

> It is useless to mount any of the rear lights we own and is ugly.

Why won't you buy a rear light or reflector that can be attached there?

A reflector costs couple of $CURRENCY_UNIT (dollars, pounds, euros, whatever).

Cutting off the bracket in a manner that looks clean will take 15 minutes or even half an hour, and still you're uncertain whether the result will look clean until the job is done.

To me, the choice is clear. Unless you're planning to be unemployed for the rest of your life, your time probably has a value. Buying a reflector is the cheapest option overall considering the value of your time, thus.

Comment: Good thought -  even easier is DOT tape which is highly reflective.  Can cut a patch to shape/size and stick it on anything hard, and it reflects well.

Comment: The argument about "your time has value" is often quoted and usually wrong. Unless you have a free choice to spend a few minutes earning more, saving the time on a DIY solution doesn't gain you money, and buying something costs. Even if you have such a rare job, you'd have to actually exercise the option and earn more; most such jobs are low paid anyway.

Answer (score 1):

On the topeak full racks I've had, the light bracket isn't structural, as it only attaches at the top. I don't know the explorer though, only the super tourist. If I really wanted to get rid of it I'd use a junior hacksaw to cut it off as cleanly as possible, maybe assembling the blade into the handle while threading it through the rack. Then I'd finish with a file.

If your rack is black you've then got a cut edge showing. Black sharpie imitates black anodising fairly well, but will fade in sunlight. Black nail polish would also work but may chip

Other brands make lights that fit the same holes, which is useful if you want to leave a rear light fitted with low risk of theft. This includes some very cheap but effective lights, though they're often poorly sealed.

---

Here's a Topeak rack with a 12V strobe light.  Notice there's a plastic adapter between the metal frame, and the light's base.  The plastic piece came with this particular rack.

[image]

There is one coarse-thread screw at the top, mostly obscured by power wire.  Then the light has two bolts through the plastic adapter or "interposer"

[image]

Comment: @Criggie yes, of course.

Comment: feel free to revert or edit if that doesn't show something useful.